# Compare Two Data tables values and add to new data table if different for add, update and delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatables

How can I add similar values from two `DataTable`s **A** and **B** (same columns/rows may be different) to a new `DataTable` **C** for CRUD operations containing the similar values of first 2 Data Tables? Please advise.

Comment: Please put some effort into your problem, write a simple algorithm to start with then code and see if it breaks and if it does try to debug and if you still can not, post the code with an explanation as to what the output should be and what it is. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Look like you don't put your effort to resolve it. Any there it is you can do to resolve your problem.

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add("MyId");
table1.Columns.Add("Column1");
table1.Columns.Add("Column2");

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("Column3");
table2.Columns.Add("MyId");
table2.Columns.Add("Column4");

DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
table3.Columns.Add("Column5");
table3.Columns.Add("MyId");
table3.Columns.Add("Column6");

foreach (DataRow drtable1 in table1.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataRow drtable2 in table2.Rows)
    {
       if (Convert.ToString(drtable1["MyId"]) == Convert.ToString(drtable2["MyId"]))
                {
                    table3.Rows.Add(drtable1["MyId"], drtable1["Column1"], drtable1["Column2"]);
                }
    }
 }
```